# Error restoring database on new SQL server instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database backup on a newly installed named instance on SQL Server 2008 R2. I have several other named instances on the same server and have no problems restoring database backups but when I try the restore on the new instance I get as far as the "Specify Backup" dialog and click the "Add" button and instead of getting the "Locate Backup File" dialog I get the following error ...

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: localhost\DEVSERVER1
>   Error Number: 213
>   Severity: 16
>   State: 7
>   Procedure: xp_fixeddrives
>   Line Number: 1

I installed SP2 for the instance and rebooted the server but I still get the above issue. A named instance that restores fine and the new named instance with errors are showing the same version in SQL Server Mgmt Studio 10.50.4000.

I am starting SQL Server Mgmt Studio as Administrator. Still no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does MS SQL Server administrator have access to backup folder ?

Comment: And check it http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;956179